# Plist for windows

Tags: iphone, plist

Is there any plist editor for windows that is not showing the XML but works like a table like the one in x-code ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found this page using google: 
http://www.filebuzz.com/files/Property_List_Editor/1.html

Don't know if it helps... but they seem to have some propertylist editors.